# Cross compiling with shared dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, linker, cross-compiling, dynamic-linking

In my C++ project, I'm compiling and linking against a library that makes use of OpenSSL.

I need to compile this project for my BeagleBone which has `openssl` installed by default. I have downloaded `libssl-dev` on my development machine.

Thus, I can compile the project fine if I'm compiling for my development machine on `x86_64`, but I am not able to successfully cross compile:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

This indicates I need to have `armhf` binaries for OpenSSL, which seems a bit of a waste really since I have them on my BeagleBone if it *can just be patient and wait until I deploy it*.

Is the only way around this cross-compiling OpenSSL myself? Where would I then need to install the `.so` files (I guess `make install` would be a bad idea?)

Comment: Well that's what I've done. OpenSSL makes .a files by default so it's not too bad to solve. I just specify the library directory where the .a files are for my dependency's LDFLAGS. It does require I build OpenSSL with `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This indicates I need to have armhf binaries for OpenSSL

Correct.

> which seems a bit of a waste really since I have them on my BeagleBone if it can just be patient and wait until I deploy it.

You appear to think that shared libraries are *only* needed at runtime, but that is not the case.

`ELF` stands for executable *and linking* format. The `.so` is very much needed at static link time to construct various tables in the main executable, which will then be used by the loader at runtime to resolve references from the main executable to the `.so`.

If you are familiar with Win32, you can think of `.so` as a combination of Win32 `.LIB` and `.DLL` packed into a single file.